# Aligning image contour to map coordinates - ways to solve?

Tags: approximation, coordinate-systems, image-processing

Got an exotic problem I guess, but still.

Let's say, I have an random image contour, created bu Laplace or Sobel algorithm. Also - I have a random set of coordinates (pretty dense one for example).

Is there any way I can use piecewise linear curve approximation for that contour based ONLY on that set of coordinates?

Comment: Yes there are ways you can do it. But too application specific questions are often encouraged by the moderators on here to be asked at one of the more applied stack exchanges. Maybe signal processing or computational sciences. So please don't be discouraged if some moderators react like that.

Comment: Its okay, I came here from main stack exchange (they sent me here). I'm sure its not a signal processing question, more about math theory behind my problem (give me direction :) ).